# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I keep on getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'.  It was working fine, until a few days ago and I can't seem to find the problem.  It seems like jquery-ui is being loaded so I don't understand why the method isn't working.

My code:

```
<link href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: "autocomplete_members.php?term="+ $("#tags").val()
        }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var inner_html = '<a href="#" onclick="setId(\'' + item.id + '\');"><img src="' + item.img + '" width="40px" height="40px" style="vertical-align: middle;padding-bottom: 2px;padding-right: 4px;" />' + item.value + '</a>';
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append(inner_html)
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
    });
});

function setId(val){
    document.getElementById("member-id-text").value = val;
};
});
</script>

-------------------------------------------HTML-----------------------------------

<input id="tags" size="35"/>
<input type="hidden" name="member-id-text" id="member-id-text" />
```

Comment: shoudn't it be `.autoComplete({` - with capital "C"

Comment: why dont you downlad customised version of jqueryUI which has autocomplete functionality..

Comment: @techfoobar I tried it but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @techfoobar Not according the jQueryUI API: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @CodeJack I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  I did download the jqueryUI package specifically for autocomplete.

Comment: Are the links to jQuery and jQueryUI correct? Also, you have three nested document ready handlers - you only need one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tanveer433/NsvBL/ not giving any error for me

Comment: According to Chrome's network analyzer jquery and UI loaded.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok I got rid of the main document ready handler, should that make a difference?

Comment: I don't know if it'll fix the problem, but it won't hurt.

Comment: Works on JSFiddle like CodeJack said.  I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Yes, i see now.

Comment: just check in the resources whether 'jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js' getting loaded or not..

Comment: @CodeJack, yes it's getting loaded according to Resources.

Comment: one more way is make a breakpoint at autocomplete line and check whether both jquery files are loaded by the time line executes..

Comment: one more error am seeing is '#tags' doesnt have 'type=text'..dont know how much it matters as it was running in jsfiddle..

Comment: I had a similar problem. I was accidentally including a second, older, copy of jquery because I was had an outdated reference to the Teleirk controls:              @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar())
Removing that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the problem.  I was including a header on the page that used JQuery but not JQueryUI, for some reason these to clashed (still not entirely sure why) including the JQueryUI script in the header fixed the problem.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove the header or
change the position of the header including.

Place your Header at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i changed `<div id="header">` to `<div id="topheader">`. problem solved. still dont know how

Answer (score -2):

try this: jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Your answer is incomplete, it does not provide a context or an explanation. How does it solve the problem?