# ASP.NET Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getTotalMilliseconds' ScriptManager (After upgrade .NET Framework)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

as i mentioned at the title after i changed my .NET framework version 3.5 to 4.5 or 4.0 my javascript codes stopped working because ScriptManager throwing the below exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getTotalMilliseconds'
```

This method was point to

```
span.getTotalMiliseconds()
```

in ScriptResource.axd...

**Everything is working fine in .NET Framework 3.5 i changed my whole dependencies to corresponding framework, i mean i upgraded AjaxControlToolkit to 4.5 too, with Nuget Package Manager..But above exception still exists..**

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: you mean my master page html ?

Comment: Here's i post it on microsoft forums, http://forums.asp.net/p/1965230/5618831.aspx?p=True&t=635270297940549885&pagenum=1

Comment: Can you remove all your ajaxControl Toolkit references in the code and see if that fixes it?

Comment: When i remove this line :
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
everything works fine... But i have to put it.

Comment: Can this be similar to what you're issue is? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228852/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-autocomplete

Comment: nope, i already included JqueryUI and it's totaly a different problem. My problem is about ScriptManager

Comment: I would check the web.config then to see if the version # are correct to match the new ajax Control toolkit lib.

Comment: Thanks for the help i found the answer :) @below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by deleting and adding Scriptmanager back again from toolbox. And everything started to work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: If i know the trick, i would share it.. But after changing .NET framework Scriptmanager should be re-placed from toolbox. That's all i can say..